# Creating Elasticsearch cluster from three servers

Tags: elasticsearch

We have three physical servers. Each server has 2 CPUs (32 cores), 96 TB HDD, and 768 GB RAM. We would like to use these servers in an Elasticsearch cluster.

Each server will be located in a different data center, connecting each server using a private connection.

How can be optimize our configuration for high performance? Also, how should we best run Elasticsearch on these machines. For example, should we use virtualization to create multiple nodes per machine, or not?

Answer (score 0):

As you have huge RAM(768) available on each physical server and [according to ES documentation on heap setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/important-settings.html#heap-size-settings) it shouldn't cross 32 GB, so you will have to use virtualization to create multiple nodes per physical server for better ultization of your infra.

Apart from these there are various cluster settings and node settings which you can optimize but as you have not provided them, its difficult to provide recommendation on them.

Another thing to note is that you have huge RAM and disk but CPU is not in proportion to it, so if you can increase them as well, it would be good.